# choropleth plotly with shapefiles not working

Tags: r, plotly, choropleth

I'm downloading Fema's shapefiles (https://hazards.fema.gov/nri/data-resources) because I want to add a layer of my own data on top of it.

```
library(sf);library(dplyr);library(plotly)
counties=st_read(dsn="~/Climate Change/NRI_Shapefile_Counties/NRI_Shapefile_Counties.shp")

counties_geo=sf_geojson(counties)

fig <- plot_ly()
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(
  type="choropleth",
  geojson=counties_geo,
  locations=counties_geo$COUNTYFIPS,
  z=counties_geo$RISK_SCORE,
  showscale=T,
  text = ~paste(counties_geo$COUNTY, "<br>Risk Rating:", counties_geo$RISK_RATNG), # Hover text
  hoverinfo = "text",
  marker=list(line=list(width=0))
  
)

fig
```

How come this doesn't work?

Comment: Could you clarify what part of the code you shared isn't working for you? Are you having trouble downloading the shapefiles, or plotting them? Or a different issue?

Comment: I have trouble plotting them, and turning them in geojson format to help plot them

Comment: On the FEMA page you link to, which files are you downloading and then trying to plot? I see 5 shapefiles for the National Risk Index on the page.

Comment: I am downloading this: https://hazards.fema.gov/nri/Content/StaticDocuments/DataDownload//NRI_Shapefile_Counties/NRI_Shapefile_Counties.zip and unziping it in my folder location and using the .shp file

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you are trying to access variables from the geojson, then the variables need to be quoted. I couldn't get this to work with the hover text yet so I left that out of the code for now.

```
library(sf);library(dplyr);library(plotly);library(geojsonsf);
counties_geo=sf_geojson(counties)

fig <- plot_ly()
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(
  type="choropleth",
  geojson=counties_geo,
  locations="COUNTYFIPS",
  z="RISK_SCORE",
  showscale=T,
  hoverinfo = "text",
  marker=list(line=list(width=0))
  
)
fig
```

You can also access the variables from the shapefile (that was imported as a list) using the `$` operator. In this case you want to get variables form `counties`, *not* from `counties_geo`. See below:

```
fig <- plot_ly()
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(
  type="choropleth",
  geojson=counties_geo,
  locations=counties$COUNTYFIPS,
  z=counties$RISK_SCORE,
  showscale=T,
  hoverinfo = "text",
  marker=list(line=list(width=0))
  
)
fig
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it shows me a gray screen when I run it